# Index of second least significant set bit

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

How can you get the index of the second least significant bit? For example if `x=136` this should be `8` (using 1-indexing).

The indexing is from the least significant bit.  For example:

```
bin(136)
'0b10001000'
```

If `x=88` the output should be `5`.

To make this work properly we also need a test that the number of bits set is at least 2.  Luckily `bin(x).count('1')` will do that.

There are answers for finding the least significant bit at [return index of least significant bit in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520655/return-index-of-least-significant-bit-in-python?rq=1) (although at least one of the answers seems to be wrong).

Comment: how does this work? e.g. `(1 + (0x88 ^ 0x87)) >> 1` == `8`. While, it should be 4. i think i'm missing something.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Oh thank you! It seems it didn't work. Fixed question.

Comment: it seems what you really want is something like `len(bin(x ^ (x-1))) - 2`, which gives the correct value of 4 for 0x88 (which is the correct value), and should work for other values as well. it involves a string cast, which is going to be slower i guess, but in python, it might not make much difference.

Comment: that answer doesn't return the _index_, it returns the _lowest power of 2_. which means that in `10001000`, you want it to return `4` - the index of the lowest bit. it actually returns `1000` - the _value_ of that lowest bit, which you then have to take the log(2) of someway.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman bin(88) = '0b1011000' so the second least significant bit is at index 5 from the right, starting at 1.

Comment: confused 88 with 0x88. you are correct, for the second set LSB for 88.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for gathering the nth set LSB, you might want to separate into getting rid of lower LSBs, and actually finding the index. To mask off a bit, you do need its value; you don't need to calculate its index. You can defer the index finding until the end. i.e.:

```
x = 0x188
# Find the value of the lowest bit, to clear.
least_power_of_2_x = ((x ^ (x-1)) + 1) >> 1
least_power_of_2_x
0x8

# Clear that bit
x = x ^ least_power_of_2_x
x
0x180

# Use same algorithm to find the next least
next_least = ((x ^ (x-1)) + 1) >> 1
next_least
0x80

# Now, you have the bit you actually care about. Find its index, 1-indexed.
next_least_index = len(bin(next_least)) - 2
next_least_index
8
```

Comment: I am not sure this works. x = 0x188 is the same as x = 392. bin(392) =  '0b110001000'.  Now least_power_of_2_x = 4.  bin(x^4) = '0b110001100'  which hasn't cleared the bit.  Why are you doing it in hex out of interest?

Comment: maybe mixing algorithms? `392 ^ 391` == `15`, or `0xf`. `(15+1)<<2` == `8`, not `4`. ? Also, I use hex because when dealing with bitwise operations, hex or binary are easier for me to visualize than decimal, and hex numbers are shorter to type.

Comment: You have >> in your answer not <<.

Comment: you are right.. my fault, it was supposed to be `>> 1`, not `>> 2`. now it should be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Mask off the least significant bit, then find the least significant bit.

Borrowing from my [answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059264/242457):

```
def fss(x):
    """Returns the index, counting from 1, of the
    second least significant set bit in `x`.
    """
    x = x & (x-1)
    return (x&-x).bit_length()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can get the least significant position, simply remove it from the variable and apply once again the same reasoning.

```
get_least( x - ( 1 << get_least(x) ) )
```

(assuming get_least returns 0 indexed bit numbers)

or in functional form

```
def get_least(x):
  return ...........

def get_second_least(x):
  return get_least( x - ( 1 << ( get_least(x) ) ) )
```

Comment: corrected mistakes - instead of xor, and (least-1), as your method returns 1 indexed bit numbers. Now it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the bits from lsb to msb.  You can also use this to get the nth least bit.

```
def get_nth_least_bit(x, n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,x.bit_length()):
        sum += (x >> i) & 1
        if sum == n :
                return i + 1
    return -1
```

Note: bit_length() is only in python 2.7 and 3

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak python but this is how I would do it in c syntax. It should be easy to port over.

```
    int get2ndMSBIndex(int x) {

        x = x & (x - 1);   // Turn off rightmost 1-bit
        x = x & (-x);      // Isolate rightmost 1-bit. will be zero if none

        int pos = 0;

        while (x != 0) {
            x = x >> 1;
            pos++;
        }

        return pos;
    }
```

Comment: This assumes only 8-bit integers?

Comment: it applies to any size. just keeping it short for the example. you would need to expand case block, or write a loop. The point is that the bit is isolated.

Comment: OK. Updated answer. Also, you don't have to check beforehand because it will return 0 if no bits. Good luck. Take care.